# Unable to create record of public custom setting of manage package

Tags: package

I have a public list custom setting included in manage package.

Salesforce standard User is not able to create the record of that custom setting after installing the package.

How can I give custom setting access to the user as custom settings or not visible in profile and permission sets?

Comment: Are you creating the custom setting record in Apex code or through the Setup user interface?

Comment: Custom setting record is created through mange pacakge code, but it is throwing error.
So, I tried to create custom setting record from UI, but New button was not there.

I had installed manage package on scratch org. Is scratch org have some restrictions for manage package ?